# set new GET XMLHttpRequest() after an XML HttpRequest POST Request after onload Function with passing data

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently trying to pass data ( Variable "x" from a POST XMLHttpRequest after an onload function to make another new GET XMLHttpRequest. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
<script>

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'https://reporting.xxxxxxx.com/xxxx/reports', true);

    xhr.onload = function () {

    var x = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    x=x.taskId;
    console.log("Response Text URL = " + x);

var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr2.open('GET', x, true);  // here i would like to use the data from variable "x" ....
    xhr2.onload = function() {



}

xhr.send();
xhr2.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there. From what i'm seeing you have to put your  xhr.send(); after the xhr.onload function and not inside it.

Comment: thanks very much :)

Comment: No problem. Cheers.